# Does it make sense to correlate overall calculated value and values that add up to this overall?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, spearman-rho

I want to find the correlation between a computed overall value and a set of values that add up to this overall value. Is this possible or am I simply doing something that doesn't make sense?

In my example the overall value tells how satisfied a user is with a product from a survey. This overall value is calculated by a set of questions that the user answers from 1-4 (where 1 is very dissatisfied and 4 is very satisfied). These questions are divided into categories (for example quality, service, price and so on). I want to find the correlation between each of these category and the overall value.

Using Pearson or Spearman correlation for calculating the correlation gives me correlations that looks kind of sane but do they actually give any value as the overall is a product of these values?